# Tacker Installation with OpenStack Packstack

Tags: centos7, openstack, orchestration

I have installed OpenStack using PackStack on CentOS-7. I need to install successfully Tacker service with OpenStack PackStack on CentOS-7.

Any help on this would be helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official openstack guide to install tacker https://docs.openstack.org/tacker/latest/install/manual_installation.html

There are `.rpm` packages in RDO repositories called `openstack-tacker` and `openstack-tacker-common`, install them and configure the service following the official guide.
Tacker also requires some other services (mistral and barbican) which need to be installed and configured, there are other deployment options which support deploying tacker and its dependencies in a single config, as example kolla-ansible.